# Dataframe Assignment

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe df4.
From that one I derive dataframe df_upper
After modifying df_upper df4 shows the same modification, although 
I didn't modify df4 itself. Why is that and how to avoid it? 
Is this pandas-specific or general python-related?

```
stepsize=0.1
df_upper=df4
df_upper['strike']=df_upper['strike']+stepsize
print df4
print df_upper
```

Comment: this sits at the core of python. when you assign something like `x = df4`, you merely bind that name `x` to the object represented by `df4`. this is the way python works and it's important to understand.

Answer (score 1):

you have to use df.copy() to explicit copy a pandas object.

Comment: So, this is only for Pandas objects?

Comment: it's the Pandas manifestation of a python approach. Here's a blog post about 'call by value' vs 'call by reference' http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2012/11/13/is-python-callbyvalue-or-callbyreference-neither/

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing me on this. I was absolutely not aware of it. According to  [link](http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2012/11/13/is-python-callbyvalue-or-callbyreference-neither/) lists are also mutable. However, when I try 
    i=[1]
    j=i
    j=[2]
    print i
i is not mutated.